# How to favorite a server in-game?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Is there a way to easily favorite a server while a match?

I've looked through the [list of console commands](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/List_of_TF2_console_commands_and_variables) but haven't found anything of much use.

The closest commands I have found are:

> **cl_ask_favorite_for_any_server:**
>
> If nonzero, auto-ask for local/LAN servers (for debugging)
>
> ---
>
> **cl_ask_favorite_min_session_duration:**
>
> If player stays on a server for longer than this time (in seconds) prompt to add server to favorites
>
> ---
>
> **cl_ask_favorite_opt_out:**
>
> If nonzero, don't auto-ask to favorite servers

However these don't allow me to just add the sever to my favorites at anytime i wish.

I'm looking for something like `cur_server_favorite =1`

*~Maybe I've just missed something incredibly obvious but please someone point it out!*

Comment: please define 'in-game' more specifically. Is navigating to the server browser's history tab and then adding to favorites from there acceptable?

Comment: @ColinD, by in-game, i mean during a match

Comment: So what you're really asking is 'can I bind a key to favorite a server'.

Comment: @ColinD yes! or any other method!

Comment: @char1es I doubt there is a console command you can use, as there is not one for css http://css.gamebanana.com/threads/186556.

Comment: @ColinD Do you know of any reason why valve hasn't implemented this seemingly simple feature?

Comment: Probably the same reason Half-Life 3 still hasn't come out yet. Not even joking! Programming takes time is the reason. And this 'seemingly simple feature' is a very narrow use case. It's not that much trouble to just open up the history tab on your server browser and add it there, so most people aren't clamoring for it to be a bindable key.  As a programmer, I can tell you that it would be non-trivial to make that possible.

Comment: @Zibbobz As a software developer myself, i realize that programming takes time. And you're correct that this feature is probably not high on their list of priorities. I was simply wondering if Valve ever made a statement concerning this.

Answer (score 4):

The console isn't needed for this at all though there probably is a console command for it.  Simply press ESC to open up the menu overlay and press the "Change Server" button.  This opens the server browser with the server you're playing on highlighted, right click and select "add to favourites".  Don't worry, everyone misses 'obvious' things.

Comment: There's also an "Add current server" button in the favorites tab, no right-clicking needed.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of both these functionalities, and maybe my question isn't specific enough, but really looking for a method to be able to simply press a key (maybe f8 or something) that would simply add the server to my favorites. I assumed that this must be done with console commands and key binding.

Comment: I looked around but I think what you want may be impossible then.  While you can bind a key, there is no favourite current server command.  I looked for both generic source commands and commands specific to team fortress 2.  The valve page on bind which also links to a list of commands is here https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Bind.  The team fortress page is here: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/List_of_useful_console_commands

Comment: From my understanding, steam servers is independent from the game itself, since you can access it from outside the game. So this means there is no possible way to bind keys to any of it's actions.

Comment: Whether the servers are part of Valves network/part of steam and whether you can bind "add to favourites" are unrelated.  The server browser has a list of IP's, so the question is asking whether or not you can bind an action (list the IP as a favourite) to a key.

Answer (score 2):

1. "status" command
2. Copy server IP:Port
3. Go to Favorites tab in Server Browser
4. Click "Add a server" button at the bottom an paste the IP:Port

Comment: Is there a script that you can make to go through these steps?

Comment: @char1es Old topic, but you should be able to set up Auto Hotkey to do this.